# panorama item swipe from left to right

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to make an Arabic windows phone 8 app , so i need to make my panorama view to swipe from left to right (The opposite direction in English language) i tried this

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPanorama.DefaultItem = MainPanorama.Items[1];
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
```

but the title goes the opposite direction , anyone have an idea ?

Comment: You can also swipe from left to right by default in panorama template right? What do you want to achieve? Explain it clearly.

Comment: i want to swipe in an opposite direction than the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will the solution is very easy , there is a property on the panorama control named "FlowDirection" you change it like that

```
<phone:Panorama x:Name="MainPanorama" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that next panorama item seems to be on left, then you can play with CompositeTransforms. Something like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaTitleTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               FontSize="48"
                               Margin="12,24"
                               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   FontSize="52"
                   MinWidth="380"
                   TextAlignment="Right">
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <phone:Panorama Title="Panorama"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                    TitleTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaTitleTemplate}">
        <phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
        </phone:Panorama.RenderTransform>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Header1"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate}">

            <phone:PanoramaItem.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
            </phone:PanoramaItem.RenderTransform>

            <Grid Background="DarkBlue" />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Header2"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate}">

            <phone:PanoramaItem.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
            </phone:PanoramaItem.RenderTransform>

            <Grid Background="DarkCyan" />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Header3"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PanoramaItemHeaderTemplate}">

            <phone:PanoramaItem.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
            </phone:PanoramaItem.RenderTransform>

            <Grid Background="DarkGoldenrod" />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>


</Grid>
```